# Need to understand cause of Android Studio inspection "condition is always true" in my quoted code

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is the code:

```
    Pair<Boolean, String> updateServer() {
        final String LOG_TAG = "WS.UST.updateServer";

        Pair<Boolean, String> retVal = null;

        URL url;
        String sRawResponse = null;
        JSONObject joResponse = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://www.abc.in/v3.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            final int response = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (response != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                throw new IOException("Server response code (" + String.valueOf(response) + ") is not OK.");

            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            char[] cBuf = new char[1024];
            for (int cRead = isReader.read(cBuf, 0, 1024); cRead != -1; cRead = isReader.read(cBuf, 0, 1024))
                s.append(cBuf, 0, cRead);
            isReader.close();

            sRawResponse = s.toString();
            joResponse = new JSONObject(s.toString());

            retVal = new Pair<>(joResponse.optBoolean("success"), joResponse.optString("message"));
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, sRawResponse == null ? "null" : sRawResponse);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, joResponse == null ? "null" : joResponse.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            retVal = new Pair<>(false, e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            retVal = new Pair<>(false, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Android Studio is showing warning `Value 'joResponse' is always 'null' more... (Ctrl+F1)` in the second line of first catch block and I'm unable to understand why. Can anyone help me understand the cause of the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit simple, but require your attention toward the flow in which exception may arise. Let's discuss the flow of exception raising in your code.

You have added two exceptions in your first `catch` block `IOException & JSONException`. Initially you have `joResponse = null`, now moving downward in your code. `IOException` can be generated by `InputStreamReader` and till this point you haven't assigned any value to `joResponse`. Further `JSONException` is raised when you are trying to make `JSONObject` from `String`, since this line will raise the exception so `joResponse` will not be assigned any value again here also.

So if your program ever reached to first `catch` block, then its sure that `joResponse` will be `null`. Hence the warning by Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you. Never imagined that Android Studio would inspect code so thoroughly!

Comment: @YogeshM, it's not really that complex of an analysis: especially when both exceptions are checked, compilers have to inspect for their presence anyway to track if they've not been declared as method `throws` or caught and rethrown. And then, since that information is available anyway, it's a quality of life thing to take it and use to point at less severe problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, if IOException occurs, the code stops executing at "new URL(..);" or connection.getResponseCode(), etc. Any IOException will occur before you assign joResponse. Hence at the IOException catch block, joResponse is always null. If JSONException has occurred, something has happened at time of assignment and hence joResponse is null.

Answer (score 0):

`IOException | JSONException` (if occurs) will always occur before `joResponse` is initialized in your code. Hence the warning.